# SQL Server T-SQL: automate re-occuring SQL reports with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

**GOAL:** create a stored procedure that automates this report, so that when `execute NameOfStoredProc` is run, it does all 3 blocks and returns the query in block 3.

For into table, I want it to be dynamic based on `getdate()`.

(I did not post actual table elements and records, but if needed I can make up something b/c actual data is sensitive)

- Database: `FY1516`
- From table: `v_all_claim` (actually a view)
- Into table: `March2017_Payments`

Here's the code that I execute manually to generate the report.

Block 1:

```
--creates payment table
SELECT Recipient_ID, DOP, Provider_ID, program_code, poverty_code 
INTO FY1516..March2017_Payments
FROM FY1516..v_all_Claim
WHERE amount <> 0 
  AND DOP BETWEEN '20170301' AND '20170331'
```

**Block 2:**

```
-- add one column to the table created in block 1, sets default value to '' and update to Y 
-- if certain constraints are met
ALTER TABLE FY1516..March2017_Payments
    ADD TITLE21_Flag varchar(1);
GO 

UPDATE FY1516..March2017_Payments
SET TITLE21_Flag = ''
GO 

UPDATE FY1516..March2017_Payments
SET TITLE21_Flag = 'Y'
WHERE program_code IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

**Block 3** with select statement that gets copied into Excel:

```
SELECT * 
FROM FY1516..March2017_Payments
```

My attempts thus far:

- `@start` and `@end` are for `between @start and @end`
- `@previousMonth` gives first 3 letters of previous month
- `@previousMonthYear` gives the YYYY of the previous month

Hoping `@previousMonth +@previousMonthYear +"_Payments"` can be the tablename

```
USE FY1516

CREATE PROCEDURE NameOfStoredProc
AS
    DECLARE @start VARCHAR(8), @end VARCHAR(8),
            @previousMonth VARCHAR(3), @previousMonthYear VARCHAR(4);

    SET @start = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONHT, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0), 112)
    SET @end = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1, -1), 112)

    SET @previousMonth = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())), 3)
    SET @previousMonthYear = YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: So you're looking for a way to dynamically create tables based on @previousMonth +@previousMonthYear +"_Payments" as the file name?

Comment: Yes.  That's the critical part.  I have a working code stored procedure that creates the table using a STATIC table name.  But I can't include the update commands within that same procedure, because the table isn't created within the stored procedure but only created after `execute`.  I figured I can create a second stored procedure that executes the first stored procedure and than updates onto the table created.

Comment: Check out my answer. You can use a single stored proc. The table will be available after the `sp_executesql` command. But if you're doing everything programatically, you might need to wrap any subsequent inserts or updates in dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine Block 1 and Block 2 into a single statement:

```
--creates payment table
Select Recipient_ID
, DOP
, Provider_ID
,program_code
,poverty_code 
,TITLE21_Flag = CASE WHEN program_code IN ('A','B','C') THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END
INTO FY1516..March2017_Payments
FROM FY1516..v_all_Claim
WHERE amount <> 0 and DOP between '20170301' and '20170331'
```

Then, in your proc, you can use dynamic SQL to create your tables. Here's an example:

```
Create procedure NameOfStoredProc
AS
declare @start varchar(8)
, @end varchar(8)
,@previousMonth varchar(3)
,@previousMonthYear varchar(4);

set @start = convert(varchar(8),dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,getdate())-1,0),112)
set @end = convert(varchar(8),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1),112)
set @previousMonth =  left(datename(month, dateadd(month,-1,getdate())), 3)
set @previousMonthYear = year(dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @previousMonth +@previousMonthYear +'_Payments (ColA int)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

You'll want to replace the `(ColA int)` with your actual column names and data types.

EDIT:

Here's an example that includes Block 1/2 into the stored proc. It checks the existence of the table first, and then runs the appropriate SELECT query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NameOfStoredProc
AS
begin
declare @start varchar(8)
, @end varchar(8)
,@previousMonth varchar(3)
,@previousMonthYear varchar(4);

set @start = convert(varchar(8),dateadd(month, datediff(month,0,getdate())-1,0),112)
set @end = convert(varchar(8),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1),112)
set @previousMonth =  left(datename(month, dateadd(month,-1,getdate())), 3)
set @previousMonthYear = year(dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'IF OBJECT_ID('''+@previousMonth +@previousMonthYear +'_Payments'', ''U'') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    print 1
    INSERT INTO FY1516..'+ @previousMonth +@previousMonthYear +'_Payments
    Select Recipient_ID
    , DOP
    , Provider_ID
    ,program_code
    ,poverty_code 
    ,TITLE21_Flag = CASE WHEN program_code IN (''A'',''B'',''C'') THEN ''Y'' ELSE '''' END
    FROM FY1516..v_all_Claim
    WHERE amount <> 0 and DOP between ''20170301'' and ''20170331''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
print 2
    Select Recipient_ID
    , DOP
    , Provider_ID
    ,program_code
    ,poverty_code 
    ,TITLE21_Flag = CASE WHEN program_code IN (''A'',''B'',''C'') THEN ''Y'' ELSE '''' END
    INTO FY1516..'+ @previousMonth +@previousMonthYear +'_Payments
    FROM FY1516..v_all_Claim
    WHERE amount <> 0 and DOP between ''20170301'' and ''20170331''
END
'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString

SET @SQLString = 'SELECT * FROM '+@previousMonth +@previousMonthYear +'_Payments'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
END
```

Comment: Aaron, in the two blocks of code you gave,  I understand both blocks by themselves, but I'm not sure how to combine the two.   While the first block has a `INTO` statement, do I write a 'INSERT INTO' over the first  block and place the entire block underneath the second block?  If so how should I reference the dynamic table when writing the `INSERT INTO`  ? =D

Comment: I added another example to the answer. It incorporates the code from Blocks 1/2 into the dynamic SQL. I also added a check to see if the table exists, since I assume the stored proc might be run when the target table does not exist, but also when the target table might exist, so we have to make sure we only create a new table if the one we want doesn't exist yet.

Comment: The code you provided allowed me to learn and create a working stored procedure that did everything I used to do manually for the report.  I really appreciate the help!